# Issue with the repeated records in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

My dataset looks like below:

[image: Dataset, Current result, Expected result]

I am trying to get Min start date & Max end date of an employee whenever there is a team change.

The problem here is, the date is not coming for repeated team.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a gaps-and-islands problem that can be solved using the difference of row number.

You can use:

```
select emp_id, team, min(month_end_date), max(month_end_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by month_end_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id, team order by month_end_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by emp_id, team, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Note:  This puts the dates on a single row, which seems more useful than your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata has a nice SQL extension for normalizing overlapping date ranges. This assumes that you want to get extra rows when a month is missing, i.e. there's a gap:

```
SELECT
   emp_id
  ,team
  -- split the Period into seperate columns again
  ,Begin(pd) 
  ,last_day(add_months(End(pd),-1)) -- end of previous month
FRO
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE -- normalize overlapping periods
      emp_id
     ,team
      -- NORMALIZE only works with periods, so create a Period based on current date plus one month
     ,PERIOD(month_end_date
            ,last_day(add_months(month_end_date, 1))
            ) AS pd
   FROM vt
 ) AS dt;
```